# Google maps v3 array marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hy i am unable to display multiple markers in Google Maps V3, i am getting the coordinates correctly but not displays on map. Also no errors in console

1. map_items[0] = title
2. map_items[1] = 55.153766, 11.909180
3. map_items[2] = link
4. map_items[3] = text

all of them appear correctly if i do an alert. 
example

"Title","51.00150763193481, -2.5659284999999272", "link", "text"

```
 function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 7,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.153766, 11.909180),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            for (var x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
                if(temp[x][1]){
                    var map_items = temp[x];
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(map_items[1]);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: myLatlng,
                        title: map_items[0]
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.setContent('<div class="google_marker"><a href="'+map_items[2]+'">'+map_items[0]+'</a><br /><p>'+map_items[3]+'</p></div>');
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the variable temp created and are you sure it contains data?

Comment: The temp variable is like 200 rows long but it's correct only the marker display is not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

google.maps.LatLng() takes two parameters, not one, so:

```
var latlon = map_items[1].split(',');
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlon[0]), parseFloat(latlon[1]));
```

though in fact, it would be better to use objects rather than an array in which each item contains different data types, for example:

```
marker_data[0] = {
  "lat": 55.153766,
  "lon": 11.909180,
  "title": "My Title",
  "link": "http://stackoverflow.com"
}
//etc...
```

and then you'd access it like this:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data[0].lat, marker_data[0].lon);
```

Comment: Tnks it worked but why? There are 2 coordinates in that variable

Comment: There are two coordinates, but the variable is a string. It's the same as "My Title", it has 2 words, but unless you split it, the variable is just one string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `map_items[1]` is string

```
if (temp[x][1]) {
    var map_items = temp[x];
    var latlng = map_items[1].split(",");
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]), parseFloat(latlng[1]));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: myLatlng,
        title: map_items[0]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<div class="google_marker"><a href="' + map_items[2] + '">' + map_items[0] + '</a><br /><p>' + map_items[3] + '</p></div>');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think only last map_items would be available when you click on any marker. Creating a different  context may solve your problem.

```
function initialize() {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 7,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.153766, 11.909180),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                function AttachEventToMarker(marker, map_items){

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                       infowindow.setContent('<div class="google_marker"><a href="'+map_items[2]+'">'+map_items[0]+'</a><br /><p>'+map_items[3]+'</p></div>');
                       infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }

                for (var x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
                    if(temp[x][1]){
                        var map_items = temp[x];
                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(map_items[1]);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: myLatlng,
                            title: map_items[0]
                        });
                         AttachEventToMarker(marker, map_items);
                    }
                }
            }
```